# JQuery Question: Dynamically populating a form

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically create a form using JQuery.

In order to do this, I have created javascript code that injects  tags into the initially empty form based on user selections. - I would not to NOT change this type of functionality if possible.

On load, my form is like this:

```
<form method="post" action="complete.jsp" id="band"> 
    <span id="select-form"></span> 
    <input type="submit" value="Create band" /> 
</form>
```

Once one item is added it looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="complete.jsp" id="band"> 
    <span id="select-form"><input type="hidden" value="hello" /></span> 
    <input type="submit" value="Create band" /> 
</form>
```

The difference being that the input field now appears.

The problem is that when the form is submitted, NO VARIABLES ARE BEING SENT!

i don't understand why, or how to fix it.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add attibute name for input form:

```
<form method="post" action="complete.jsp" id="band"> 
  <span id="select-form"><input name="xxxx" type="hidden" value="hello" /></span> 
  <input name="name" type="submit" value="Create band" /> 
</form>
```